# Create some files and folders that not exist

Tags: java, copy, nio, createfile

I should copy some files and I have a JTextField for destination file. User can enter a file path or choose a file by a JFileChooser, It is doing well, but when I enter an incorrect input. such as this: C:\Users\123\123\123
or something like this: 123
The program will crash and it cannot exit the while loop.
I have no idea about how can I fix this problem,
My createFile() function is here:

```
private void createFile(File f) {
        if (f.exists()) {
            return;
        } else {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println(1);
                if (f.getParentFile().exists()) {
                    if (f.getName().equals(dest.getName())) {
                        return;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(f.mkdirs() + " Directory created ");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println(f.getPath());
                    createFile(f.getParentFile());
                }
                if(f.exists()){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "this problem" what problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, I added the problem...

Comment: Is there a stack trace?

Comment: What is a stack trace?

Comment: Is there an error message after you crash?

Comment: No, do you need more codes?

Comment: I don't understand why you need such an elaborate solution...`if (f.getParentFile().exists() || f.getParentFile().mkdirs()) {...} else { // failed to create directories }` should just about do the same thing...

Comment: Is it working on more than 1 directory?
I think if user enter this: C:/123/123/123 and we have this destination C:/123/ your code will not work correctly, am I right?